# In Javascript, can I reference a key value pair from another key value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, key-value, keyvaluepair

```
var fighters = ['johnjones', 'rondarousey', 'connormcgregor', 'chuckliddel', 'demetriusjohnson'];

var warriors = {
  wrestlers: ['randysavage', 'hulkhogan', 'ultimatewarrior', 'jakethesnake', 'milliondollarman'],

  stable: [fighters, warriors.wrestlers]
}
```

I believe I can reference fighters from stable, but can I reference wrestlers from stable? In other words, how do I reference a key value pair from a later key value pair within the warriors object.  Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that until the variable `warriors` is initialized. The only way is to wait and assign in the next line:

```
var warriors = {
  wrestlers: ['randysavage', 'hulkhogan', 'ultimatewarrior', 'jakethesnake', 'milliondollarman'],
}
warriors.stable = [fighters, warriors.wrestlers]
```

Or use some kind of weird initialization like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616273/2545680). Or use function constructor.